# Fechas almacenada y fecha recuperada varian en BD mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs

En mi base de datos tengo la fecha almacenada `01/02/2017 15:17:34 p.m.`

Inserto así:

```
objBD.query('SELECT u.ID_U, u.nombre from USUARIO u  where u.nombre=?',[nombre], function(err, rows, fields) {
    var created = new Date();
    console.log(rows);
            var post  = {ID_U:rows[0].ID_U,  ESTADO:estado, FECHA:created};
            var query = objBD.query('INSERT INTO  INTENTO SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
                for (var q = 0; q < array.length; q++) {
                    var post  = {ID_INTENTO:result.insertId,  TIEMPOB:array[q], VARIABLEB:1};
                    var query = objBD.query('INSERT INTO  BITACORA SET ?', post, function(err, result) {    

                    }); 
                };
            });
    }); 
};
```

Pero cuando lo recupero:

```
var getBitacoraIndividual=function(nombre,done){
var objBD = BD();
let res=[];

    objBD.query("select ID_U from usuario u where u.`NOMBRE`=?",[nombre], function(err, rows, fields) {
        objBD.query("SELECT Distinct fecha FROM bitacora b join intento i on i.`ID_INTENTO`=b.`ID_INTENTO` where i.`ID_U`=?",[rows[0].ID_U], function(err, rows, fields) {
            return done(null,rows);
        });
    });

    return res;             
}
```

Me devuelve `01/02/2017 19:17:34 p.m.`.

¿Por qué obtengo la hora +4 horas?

Comment: Hola acR, si tu servidor de base de datos se encuentra en una zona horaria diferente a la del servidor de aplicaciones y cuando realizas el `INSERT` se realiza con la función `NOW()` se tomará por default la fecha del servidor de base de datos, de esta forma, cuando la recuperes, tendrás diferencias

Comment: @Flxtr cuando inserto uso var created = new Date();

Comment: @Flxtr como lo soluciono?

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta poniendo el código de MySql cuando se inserta el registo?

Comment: @Flxtr ya lo edite,

Comment: Cuando haces `var created = new Date();` ¿se genera la fecha y hora actuales del lado de tu aplicación? Otra pregunta, ¿tu servidor de la aplicación y el de la base de datos se encuentran en diferente zona horaria?

Comment: si estan en diferente zona horaria, mi servidor tiene la hora 04:53:20 y mi base de datos 00:53:20, hice la prueba :)

Comment: Eso explica la diferencia. Podrías utilizar [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) para manejar una sola zona horaria, no pareciera ser complicado

Comment: @Flxtr gracias funciono, publique  mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi instalando momentjs  http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/

codigo...

```
    var moment = require('moment-timezone');
    var created = new Date();//ver mi codigo de mi pregunta
    var created = moment.tz(created, "zonahoraria");
    created=created.format();
    console.log(created);
```

para la zona horaria ver http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php

Comment: Esto es importante. Si el uso de horas está relacionado con sucesos importantes, es vital que tengas en cuenta las zonas horarias.